# Getting several cylinders from 3D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I got a 3D scatterplot which looks like "tubes", what it in fact should display. Currently every "tube" consist out of 40 markers. What I am trying is, that these 40 markes together built a cylinder, that looks like a tube with the positional arguments from `X`, `Y`and `Z` and the coloration from `C`.

```
X = df['Tube']
Y = df['Window']
C = df['Value']
Z = df['Depth']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(X,Y,Z, marker='o',s=50, c=C, cmap = 'Reds',edgecolors= "black")

df
      Tube  Window  Value     Depth
0        1       1  0.000383  -0.1
1        1       2  0.023253  -0.1
2        1       3  0.022623  -0.1
3        1       4  0.003599  -0.1
4        1       5  0.001281  -0.1
...    ...     ...       ...   ...
2155    54      36  0.020977  -1.2
2156    54      37  0.000000  -1.2
2157    54      38  0.007104  -1.2
2158    54      39  0.015233  -1.2
2159    54      40  0.000000  -1.2
```

[image]

Does anybody has any idea how this might be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work with `mayavi.mlap`.

```
from mayavi.mlab import *
from mayavi import mlab
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

X = df['Tube']
Y = df['Window']
C = df['Value']
Z = df['Depth']

plot3d(X, Y, Z, C, tube_radius=0.25, colormap='Reds')
mlab.show()
```